# How is this dereferenced?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I'm following a tutorial, where they want to write a particular value (0x0403) to register (at address 0x04000000)

As per my knowledge, this could be done like this,

```
unsigned int 32 *ptr;
ptr = 0x04000000
*ptr = 0x403
```

However, they are doing following:

```
#define REG_DISP      *((volatile uint32*)(0x04000000))
#define VIDEOMODE_3                            0x0003
#define BGMODE_2                               0x0400

int main()
{
    REG_DISP = VIDEOMODE_3 | BGMODE_2;
    while(1){}
}
```

Now, I have following questions:

1. Can we use pointers without declaring any variables?
2. Why pointer to a pointer is used? Is it because, we cannot do ptr = 0x04000000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a remark. All this can only be implementation defined, because the language itself has no concept of registers living at well known addresses.

The standard just says at 6.3.2.3 Pointers §5 (emphasize mine):

> **An integer may be converted to any pointer type**. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

That means that this is valid C, provided the implementation allows it to make sense:

```
unsigned int *ptr;
ptr = 0x04000000;
*ptr = 0x403;
```

It just uses a named pointer to access the specific address. It can be done without naming the pointer that way:

```
* ((unsigned int *) 0x04000000) = 0x403;
```

Let us see how it works:

- `(unsigned int *) 0x04000000` converts an unsigned int to a pointer to unsigned int
- `* ((unsigned int *) 0x04000000)` dereferences that pointer
- `* ((unsigned int *) 0x04000000) = 0x403;` assigns a value to the pointed variable

As you want to access a physical register, you need to ask the compiler to immediately write the value instead of keeping it in an internal register which could be allowed per the *as if* rule. That is the meaning of the `volatile` qualifier. As it is dedicated to a specific implementation, it is perfectly legal, provided you can be sure that `unsigned int` has 32 bits in that implementation,  to write

```
volatile unsigned int *ptr;
ptr = 0x04000000;
*ptr = 0x403;
```

or

```
* ((volatile unsigned int *) 0x04000000) = 0x403;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ad. 1: C allows to convert an integral value to a pointer and vice versa. Weather you assign the (intermediate) conversion to a variable or not does not matter. Code part `(volatile uint32*)(0x04000000)` actually converts integral literal `0x0400000` to a pointer of type `uint32*`; Note the volatile, which turns off any compiler optimizations and lets the code actually access the respective memory whenever dereferened.

Ad 2: there is no pointer to pointer; `*((volatile uint32*)(0x04000000))` just dereferences the pointer (which has been explained in (1).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is about GameBoy Advance development.

You can write to a memory address without declaring any variable, a pointer is a type of value which represents a memory address, you can write and read from it without the need to store it anywhere.

It's not a pointer to a pointer, it's a hardcoded address which is cast to a `(volatile uint32*)`, and the macro adds the `*` operator in front just to save you from writing it, which is just confusing.

I'm working on a framework for GBA development right in these days, maybe you can pick some informations or code from [there](https://github.com/Jakz/gba-cpp-lib/blob/master/source/gfx.h), mind that code is C++14 though.